# Coda for iPad Pro - Javascript events not working in preview

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, coda

In Coda on my iPad Pro I have the following two files in a single directory that I named assets.  When I try to preview the template.html file either in Coda or Safari (in side by side mode) I cannot get any interaction with javascript calls on events.

I have consulted the panic library regarding this and tried searching if similar issues have been encountered, but to no avail.  The documentation clearly states that html/css/javascript rendering is supported by the preview functionality of Coda.

I have tried including the script directly in the head, the body, importing in a script tag and importing in a source tag and none have worked. CSS styling works as expected. I have tried many iterations that I won't list below, but this is the simplest case that I'm currently working with.

assets/template.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <source type="text/javascript" src="assets/scripts.js"></source>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="myheader" id="theheader">Hello?</h1>
        <button onclick="doStuff()">click me</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

assets/scripts.js

```
doStuff(){
    document.getElementById('theheader').style.color = 'red';
}
```

Comment: did you try with src="scripts.js"?

Comment: I have tried both src="scripts.js” and src="/scripts.js”.  I just retested to be sure.  It feels like it's a particular issue with Coda itself and hoping someone with experience with Coda on iPad will be able to help.